# How to prevent hotlinking only for specific website using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hotlinking

I want to be able to prevent hotlinking and show a specific image only for some domains.
I have tried this method but this prevent all sites from hotlinking using `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(.+\.)?example\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|webp)$ https://image.example/img/logo.jpg [R=301,L]
```

My question is:
Lets say for example my website is: `example.com` and I want to prevent hotlinking only for this specific domain: `domain-name.example`.
How can I modify the code above in order to prevent only that specific domain from hotlinking?

Answer (score 1):

You would put that domain name into a rewrite condition that doesn't have the negation (`!`). It would look something like this:

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain-name.example(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|webp)$ https://image.example/img/logo.jpg [R=301,L]
```

Using `(/.*)?` in this rule means "an optional URL path".  Either it ends without the slash, or it has the slash followed by anything else.  This effectively combines two of your rewrite conditions.

Comment: An edge case, however, ... if the OP is insisting on "redirecting" to block the user then this should probably be a 302 (temp) redirect, not a 301. Otherwise, if an innocent user gets caught by this and later happens to visit the site in question or another (allowed) site that is hotlinking then the image(s) will still be blocked as the browser will have cached the redirect. (Maybe a `Vary: Referer` header would also workaround this?!)